# search bar bootstrap is not displayed properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[picture of the search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCzNX.png)

Hi, I try to develop animal adoption website and i add a feature like search bar...so I create a search bar below the header, but it seems like it's not displayed properly...i already tried to put the search bar outside the card body, means between the header and the card, but it still not displayed properly...how to solve this? this is the code

```
 <body>
  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
    <header id="header" class="fixed-top">
        <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">

        <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.php">SPCA SANDAKAN</a></h1>
            <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
            <!--<a href="index.php" class="logo"><img src="assets/img/spca_logo.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>-->

        <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="index.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="index.php">Team</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Gallery</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="cat_gallery.php">Cats</a></li>
                        <li><a href="dog_gallery.php">Dogs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>  
            <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="index.php">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a class="getstarted scrollto" href="login_page.php">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
            <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
        </nav><!-- .navbar -->
        </div>
    </header><!-- End Header -->

  <!-- ======= Content ====== -->
<div class="row">
    <section>
        <main>
            <div class="card border border-dark d-grid">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search the name.." aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" />
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" type="button"> Search </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="card d-grid pl-sm-5" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/img/cat/cat1.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="card-body border border-secondary">
                            <h5 class="card-title">title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">content</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </section>
</div><!-- ======= End Content ====== -->

   <!-- ======= Footer ======= -->
   <footer id="footer">
        <div class="footer-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <center><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="footer-info">
                        <h3>SPCA Sandakan</h3>
                        <p class="pb-3"><em>We speak for those who cannot speak for themselves.</em></p>
                        <p>
                        Jalan Lai Fook Kim, Jalan Datuk Tay, <br>
                        1KM, Mile 8, 90000 Sandakan, Sabah, Malaysia.<br><br>
                            <strong>Phone:</strong> +6010 227 8911<br>
                            <strong>Email:</strong> spcasdk@gmail.com<br>
                                </p>
                        <div class="social-links mt-3">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SpcaSandakan" class="facebook"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/spcasdk/?hl=en" class="instagram"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <body>

    <header id="header" class="">
        <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">

        <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.php">SPCA SANDAKAN</a></h1>
            Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo 
           <a href="index.php" class="logo"><img src="assets/img/spca_logo.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
        </div>
    </header>

 

    <section>
        <main>
          <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search the name.." aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" />
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" type="button"> Search </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="card border border-dark d-grid">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    
                    <div class="card d-grid pl-sm-5" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/img/cat/cat1.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="card-body border border-secondary">
                            <h5 class="card-title">title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">content</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </section>

  
  
   <footer id="footer">
        <div class="footer-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <center><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="footer-info">
                        <h3>SPCA Sandakan</h3>
                        <p class="pb-3"><em>We speak for those who cannot speak for themselves.</em></p>
                        <p>
                        Jalan Lai Fook Kim, Jalan Datuk Tay, <br>
                        1KM, Mile 8, 90000 Sandakan, Sabah, Malaysia.<br><br>
                            <strong>Phone:</strong> +6010 227 8911<br>
                            <strong>Email:</strong> spcasdk@gmail.com<br>
                                </p>
                        <div class="social-links mt-3">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SpcaSandakan" class="facebook"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/spcasdk/?hl=en" class="instagram"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```